# Why is my MPMediaItem NowPlayingItem returning null?

Tags: ios6, mpmediaitem

I am incorporating the iPod player in my app.  I am able to create a queue, then play the songs.  I am not able to get the current song's property values.  I have registered for the notifications and the log shows the notifications are bing triggered.

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
NSLog(@"currentItem = %@", currentItem);
```

Log output shows: currentItem = (null)

I'm running Xcode 4.5.2 iOS 6.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else who may run into the same issue, the problem was that I synced my Music after running my application.  You need to observe for Library changes:

```
MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification

[[MPMediaLibrary defaultLibrary] beginGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications];
```

Comment: Looks promising. Thanks... I was looking for  a way to observe change in Media items.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `NSLog(@"currentItem = %@", currentItem);` in your codes but maybe you have not got a full understand of what MPMediaItem is.

MPMediaItem is not NSString, and that's why you got null here. MPMediaItem has a lot of properties including song title, album name and artist name. To access the properties of MPMediaItem such as the title, use valueForProperty: method.

```
NSLog(@"currentItem = %@", [currentItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle])
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem that I mixed by accident the application player

```
[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]
```

and the ipod player

```
[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]
```

I was using the iPodMusicPlayer for playing music and tried to adjust the volume of the applicationMusicPlayer by accident.

So just beware not to mix them unintentionally ;-)